# Need of maintaining replication factor on datanodes

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

Please pardon if this question has come up earlier as I'm not able to find any related question for this.

1) I want to know the reason why it is important to maintain the same replication factor(or for that matter any configuration) across the datanodes and namenodes in the cluster?

2) When we upload any file to HDFS, isn't it the namenode which manages the storage?

3) Wouldn't maintaining the configuration only on the namenodes suffice?

4) What are the implications of having the configuration different across namenode and datanodes?

Any Help is much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: What do you mean by maintaining the same configuration on the DataNodes? Are you referring to hdfs-site.xml file, present in the Data Node?

Comment: precisely @ManjunathBallur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your question taking replication as an example.

**Few things to keep in mind -**

Data always resides on datanodes, Namenode never deals with data or store data, it only keeps metadata about the data.

Replication factor is configurable, you can change it for every file copy, for example file1 may have replication factor of 2 while file2 may have replication factor of say 3, in a similar way some other properties can also be configured at the time of execution.

***2) When we upload any file to HDFS, isn't it the namenode which manages the storage?***
I am not sure about what you exactly mean by namenode managing the storage, here is how a file upload to hdfs gets executed -

```
1) Client sends a request to Namenode for file upload to hdfs
2) Namenode based on the configuration(if not explicitly specified by the client application) calculates the number of blocks data will be broken into.
3) Namenode also decides which Datanodes will store the blocks, based on the replication factor specified in configuration(if not explicitly specified by the client application)
4) Namenode sends information calculated in step #2 and #3 to the client
5) Client application will break the file into blocks and write each block to 'a' Datanode say DN1.
6) Now DN1 will be responsible to replicate the received blocks to other  Datanodes as chosen by the Namenode in #3; It will initiate replication when Namenode instructs it.
```

For you questions #3 and #4, it is important to understand that any distributed application will require a set of configurations available with each node to be able to interact with each other and also perform designated task as per expectation. **In case every node chooses to have its own configuration what would be the basis of co-ordination**? DN1 has replication factor of 5, while DN2 has of 2 how would data be actually replicated?

**Update start**
hdfs-site.xml contains lots of other config specifications as well for namenode, datanode and secondary namenode, some client and hdfs specific settings and not just the replication factor.

Now imagine having a 50 node cluster, would you like to go and configure on each node or simply copy a pre-configured file?

**Update end**

**If you keep all configurations at one location, each node will need to connect to that shared resource to load configuration every time it has to perform an action, this would add to latency apart from consistency/synchronization issues in case any config property is changed.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your explanation. I do know that the namenode only manages the metadata and not the data itself. What I was actually asking is, when we send an upload request through the client, it is the namenode which decides what block size is required, how the file should be replicated and all other storage considerations; so what is the use of hdfs-site.xml (as well as other configuration files) on datanodes?

Comment: Client machine have their copy of hdfs-site.xml based on the configuration client decide the block size and split the large file in blocks. after it client contact to NN to get the datnode and client place block to the datanode and then datanode replicate the block to other datanode.

Comment: Plz see the link to know more on it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873306/data-division-on-addition-of-node-to-distributed-system/30873728#30873728

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that answers my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is designed to deal with large datasets. It's not a good idea to store a large dataset on a single machine because if your storage system or hard disk crashes, you may lose all of your data.

Before Hadoop, people were using a traditional system to store large amounts of data, but the traditional system was very costly.  There were also challenges while analyzing large datasets from the traditional system as it was time consuming process to read data from the traditional system. With these things in mind, the Hadoop Framework was designed.

In the hadoop framework, when you load large amounts of data, it splits the data into small chunks, known as blocks.  These blocks are basically used to place the data into a datanode in a distributed cluster, and also they also are used during the analysis of the data.

The region behind the splitting of the data is parallel processing and distributed storage (i.e.: you can store your data onto multiple machines, and when you want to analyze it you can do it via parallel analysis).

**Now Coming to your questions:**

**Reason:** Hadoop is a framework which allows distributed storage and computing.  In other words, this means you can store the data onto multiple machines.  It has functionality of replication that means you are keeping multiple copy (based on the replication factor) of the same data.

**Ans1:** Hadoop is designed to run on the commodity hardware and failures are common on commodity hardware so suppose if you store the data on a single machine and when your machine get crashed you will lose your entire data. But in the hadoop cluster you can recover the data from another replication( if you have replication factor more than 1) as hadoop doesn't store replicated copy of the data on the same machine where your original replication resides.These things are handled from hadoop itself.

**Ans2:** When you upload file on the HDFS, your actual data goes to the datanode and NameNode keep the metadata information of your data. NameNode metadata information conatains are like block name, block location, filename, directory location of the file.

**Ans3:** You need to maintain entire configuration related to your hadoop cluster. Maintaining one configuration file is not sufficient and further you may face other problem.

**Ans4:** NameNode configurations properties are related to NameNode functionality like namespace services metadata location etc,RPC address that handles all clients requests Datanode configuration properties are related to services which is performed by the DataNode like storage balancing among the DataNode's volumes,available disk space,the DataNode server address and port for data transfer

Please check this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) to understand more about the different configuration property.

Please provide more clarification about the question 3 and 4 if you think something more you want to know.

Comment: hello! Thanks for the detailed explanation! My question actually is about maintaining the configuration files across all the nodes on the cluster e.g. hdfs-site.xml file is copied on all the nodes. Do we really need to manage the configuration files on all the nodes and keep the configuration consistent across all the nodes?

Comment: The configuration file should reside on the central repository and all the services should have the access of configuration file. If you use ClouderaManager it is handled through that. Please see the link.https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/What-is-the-Path-of-hdfs-site-xml-core-xml/td-p/15180   But if you install manually, you need to place this file across the node and all file should be consistent across the nodes. generally these files resides under `/etc/servicename/conf` directory.

Comment: You need to use the same configurations on all the nodes of hadoop cluster, i.e. you need to edit all *-site.xml files on each and every server accordingly.